# How to align string column using string format padding in C#

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting

I used string format padding to display columns in specific format (i.e distance between columns).

```
String.Format("{0,5}{1,0}{2,-20}{3,0}",
                            ID,
                            ZIP,
                            State,
                            Flag);
```

It works well for standard fixed row length.

```
012345IL     1
112345KS     0
212345CO     1
312345CA     1
412345IL     1
512345KS     0
612345CO     1
712345CA     1
812345IL     1
912345KS     0
1012345CO     1
1112345CA     1
```

But the problem comes when the ID becomes double digit and the last line shifts a bit. 
The desired format I am expecting is

```
012345IL     1
112345KS     0
212345CO     1
312345CA     1
412345IL     1
512345KS     0
612345CO     1
712345CA     1
812345IL     1
912345KS     0
1012345CO    1
1112345CA    1
```

I tried padright and padleft, but not solved the problem and I have the same problem with the other string which has address, where the last column changes when the address length increase. Is there any other way or builtin C# function to achieve?

Comment: A better idea could be the string count and use spaces instead of padding. So if the ID size is increased your location of next column will still be same.

Comment: @MohitShrivastava Can you please answer with the prototype of your concept ?

Comment: how do you show your result? Because I am seeing padded strings (spaces) in front of each result, which makes them what you wanted already

Comment: padding 0 doesn't affect the output of my format

Answer (score 4):

Your String.Format already formats your string properly.  The {0,5} allows 5 characters for the first parameter.  This will give you 4 spaces at the beginning of your line for single digit ids, and 3 for double digit ids.  Perhaps it is an issue with how you are displaying your string.

However, what you show in your requested format is a little different.
Try this:

```
string firstGroup = $"{ID}{ZIP}{State}";
String.Format($"{firstGroup,-13}{Flag}");
```

Comment: Is this syntax belongs to c# ?

Comment: @berdem:  Yes, it is called an ["interpolated string"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated).  It has been supported since [c# 6, July 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language)#Versions).